# ctrl F in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, search, filter, datagridview, ms-access-2003

I'm trying to implement an equivalent to a ctrl+F function in my project. I want it to work like in an excel where the cursor points at the matching string in any cell. It can also work as a filter that only show the rows with the matching string.

EDIT 1 : Here is what i tried when using @Gabriel Stancu 's method :

```
        Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
        'Dim search As New OleDbCommand
        'Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim dgv As DataGridView

        Dim searchedValue As String
        frmPrinc.dgv.DataSource = dt.DefaultView

        searchedValue = txtBoxName.Text
        MsgBox(searchedValue) 'Displayed
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In frmPrinc.dgv.Rows 
            MsgBox("yes") 'Not displayed
            For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                MsgBox("yes2") 'Not displayed
                If cell.Value IsNot DBNull.Value Then
                    MsgBox("yes3") 'Not displayed
                    If cell.Value.ToString().Equals(searchedValue) Then
                        cell.Selected = True
                        MsgBox(cell.Selected)
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next

    End Sub
```

this just cleared my DataGridView display

EDIT 2 : Here's what i'm currently working on using @jmcilhinney 's method :

```
    Private Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click

        Dim myBindingSource As New BindingSource
        Dim myDataTable As New DataTable
        Dim myDataGridView As New DataGridView
        myBindingSource.DataSource = myDataTable
        myDataGridView.DataSource = myBindingSource

        Dim myValue As String

        myValue = txtBoxName.Text
        
        MsgBox(myValue)
        myDataTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("NAME", GetType(String)))
        myBindingSource.DataSource = myDataTable

        myBindingSource.Position = myBindingSource.Find("NAME", myValue) 'Running fails on this line


        'myBindingSource.Filter = $"MyColumn LIKE '%{myValue}% OR MyOtherColumn LIKE '%{myValue}%'"

        Dim sourceRows = myBindingSource.Cast(Of DataRowView)().
                                 Where(Function(drv) CStr(drv("NOM")).Contains(myValue)).
                                 ToArray()

        For Each gridRow As DataGridViewRow In myDataGridView.Rows
            gridRow.Selected = sourceRows.Contains(DirectCast(gridRow.DataBoundItem, DataRowView))
        Next

    End Sub
```

This above is still work in progress but i'm a bit stuck getting a

> System.ArgumentException : 'DataMember property' NAME 'could not be found in the DataSource.'

Comment: That code makes absolutely no sense based on what you actually described. For one thing, if you're trying to execute a query, why would you call `ExecuteNonQuery`? If you're trying to to implement a *Find* function in a `DataGridView` then that implies that you already have a populated `DataGridView`, but that doesn't seem to be the case so you should learn how to do that first. Learn how to execute a query first, then learn how to populate a `DataGridView` with the results of that query. Once you've done those two things, maybe you can consider searching in that data locally.

Comment: sorry if i didn't make it clear but yes i'm just starting to learn and i already have a populated DataGridView and i was just highlighting what i tried and i do understand that this makes no sense. That's why i was looking for help in order to make this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *jmcilhinney* specified in the comments, your code has nothing to do with what you want to achieve. A first approach that comes to my mind (might not be the most efficient) would be to go row by row and column by column. Something like:

```
    Private Sub SearchCellValue(ByVal searchedValue As String)
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvSample.Rows
            For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                If cell.Value IsNot DBNull.Value And cell.Value IsNot Nothing Then 'you also need to check for the "Nothing" value
                    If cell.Value.ToString().Equals(searchedValue) Then
                        dgvSample.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect 'add this to only select a cell, not the entire row
                        cell.Selected = True
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
```

You could also search in the **DataTable** which holds the data for the **DataGridView**, get the corresponding indexes (row and column) and then select the corresponding cell in the **DataGridView** (as it is not quite the best practice to implement code logic directly on the UI which should be separated). Anyway, both approaches seem faster than looking directly in the database, as your approach suggests you intend to do.

You could also make this a **Boolean Function** and return a value (**True** if you found the value, **False** otherwise). This is just a sample code to guide you. Before jumping into complex stuff, make sure you read some documentation or at least follow some tutorials step by step.

Comment: I tried to test your code in my mess but it doesn't want to enter the `For` loop. That's weird.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Have you tried using the debugging tools to see why? For instance, go step by step and check if the datagridview has rows (it should have as you can see that in the UI). Are you sure the find method is called in the first place? Put a breakpoint and check the workflow of the application when you try to find the value in the grid. How exactly do you capture the "Ctrl+F" command from the user input?

Comment: i did put breakpoints in every step (when it gets the string , when it enter the row, cell and so on) . it shows me that it got the string right but nothing else.
I get the input from a windows form text box and get to search by pressing a button

Comment: So does it iterate through the rows and columns?

Comment: no since it only starts when the `For` loop kicks in
but i may have an idea with why it doesn't work i'll keep you updated later i'll be eating soon

Comment: edit to my previous comment it still doesn't work and now just clears out the DataGrid display without entering the breakpoint set previously

Comment: Could you please edit the question and add the code for the Button click event, the implemented Find function and any other relevant information? It is almost impossible to do the debugging if I don't even have a piece of code in front...

Comment: And where exactly does it stop? Which messageboxes are displayed?

Comment: I edited my answer also. I added a new test condition in the if value isnot dbnull.value (now the exception is not thrown anymore) and also added the selectionmode value to only select a cell. It works on my computer (on a "dummy project" with only a datagridview and a button on it), so if it does not work for you as well, you might be doing something else wrong...

Comment: okay nevermind i'm a dumb dumb i didn't fill the new data table

Comment: As I can see, my solution helped you. Please don't forget to at least cast an upvote (if you won't mark the answer as a solution also), as it helps others that come here to know which solution solved your issue (I upvoted your answer also). Have a nice day! ^^

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a populated grid then the code to search or filter has nothing at all to do with your database. What you should be doing is populating a `DataTable`, using either a data adapter or a data reader, binding that to a `BindingSource` and then binding that to your `DataGridView`, e.g.

```vb
myBindingSource.DataSource = myDataTable
myDataGridView.DataSource = myBindingSource
```

Searching or filtering is then using the `BindingSource`. To select the first record with a specific value in a specific column:

```vb
myBindingSource.Position = myBindingSource.Find("MyColumn", myValue)
```

To filter out rows that don't contain a partial value in any column:

```vb
myBindingSource.Filter = $"MyColumn LIKE '%{myValue}% OR MyOtherColumn LIKE '%{myValue}%'"
```

To select each row in the grid that matches those conditions without actually filtering:

```vb
Dim sourceRows = myBindingSource.Cast(Of DataRowView)().
                                 Where(Function(drv) CStr(drv("MyColumn")).Contains(myValue)).
                                 ToArray()

For Each gridRow As DataGridViewRow In myDataGridView.Rows
    gridRow.Selected = sourceRows.Contains(DirectCast(gridRow.DataBoundItem, DataRowView))
Next
```

Comment: i'm not sure what the "MyColumn" and "myOtherColumn" refer to. When do i declare them ?

Comment: You don't declare them anywhere. They're the names of the columns in your `DataTable`, which are almost certainly going to be same as your database columns.

Answer (score 2):

Okay thanks to @Gabriel Stancu this worked for me :

```
    Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
       
        Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim dgv As New DataGridView

        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter("*", getConnexion) ' * here are my columns name
        Dim cmdBuilder As New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
        cmdBuilder.QuotePrefix = "["
        cmdBuilder.QuoteSuffix = "]"
        da.Fill(dt) 'here is what i forgot
        dgv.DataSource = dt.DefaultView
        Dim searchedValue As String
        frmPrinc.dgv.DataSource = dt.DefaultView

        searchedValue = txtBoxName.Text
        'MsgBox(searchedValue) 'breakpoint to make sure the input string was correct
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In frmPrinc.dgv.Rows
            For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                If cell.Value IsNot DBNull.Value And cell.Value IsNot Nothing Then 'you also need to check for the "Nothing" value
                    If cell.Value.ToString().Equals(searchedValue) Then
                        frmPrinc.dgv.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect 'add this to only select a cell, not the entire row
                        cell.Selected = True
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
```